# Division inside Insert stored procedure T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, odbc, sql-server-2008-express

I'm new to T-SQL and I was wondering if it's possible to do something like this

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [SISACT].[new_activo_fijo]
  @activo VARCHAR(8) ,
  @descripcion VARCHAR(60) ,
  @utiliza_serial BIT,
  *@serial VARCHAR(20) = NULL,*
  @fecha_adquisicion DATE,
  @referencia VARCHAR(10),
  @costo_adquisicion FLOAT,
  @vida_util INT,
  **@saldo_a_depreciar FLOAT = @costo_adquisicion / @vida_util,**
  @ultimo_periodo CHAR(6),
  *@periodo_saldo_cero CHAR(6) = NULL,*
  @fecha_incorporacion DATE,
  @fecha_desincorporacion DATE,
  @proveedor VARCHAR(8),
  @situacion INT
AS
INSERT INTO [SISACT].[ACTIVOS_FIJOS] (
activo, descripcion, utiliza_serial, serial, fecha_adquisicion, 
referencia, costo_adquisicion, vida_util, saldo_a_depreciar,
ultimo_periodo, periodo_saldo_cero, fecha_incorporacion,
fecha_desincorporacion, proveedor, situacion
)
VALUES(
  @activo, @descripcion, @utiliza_serial, @serial, @fecha_adquisicion,
  @referencia, @costo_adquisicion, @vida_util, @saldo_a_depreciar, 
  @ultimo_periodo, @periodo_saldo_cero,  @fecha_incorporacion,
  @fecha_desincorporacion, @proveedor, @situacion
)
```

Also, is it possible to initialize a parameter to NULL like I did just in case nothing sends from the form or should I do that when I'm sending the parameters?

I'm sorry if I'm asking something really basic, I'd appreciate the help.

Just in case, I'm using PHP and ODBC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on experimentation, here's what I found:

1. Can you do this: `@saldo_a_depreciar FLOAT = @costo_adquisicion / @vida_util`. Answer: **no**, SQL Server (2012 in my case) says `Incorrect syntax near '/'`. Wrapping it in parentheses (the last resort of the desperate :-) didn't help either.
2. Can you do this: `@periodo_saldo_cero CHAR(6) = NULL`. Answer: **yes**, and if `@periodo_saldo_cero` isn't passed it defaults to NULL.

As for your `@saldo_a_depreciar` column: is it always defined as `@costo_adquisicion / @vida_util`? If so you should calculate it as needed rather than storing it.

If `@saldo_a_depreciar` really is a value that should be stored rather than calculated, you just need to push the calculation into the procedure code rather than the parameter list:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [SISACT].[new_activo_fijo]
  @activo VARCHAR(8) ,
  @descripcion VARCHAR(60) ,
  @utiliza_serial BIT,
  @serial VARCHAR(20) = NULL,
  @fecha_adquisicion DATE,
  @referencia VARCHAR(10),
  @costo_adquisicion FLOAT,
  @vida_util INT,
  @saldo_a_depreciar FLOAT = NULL
  @ultimo_periodo CHAR(6),
  @periodo_saldo_cero CHAR(6) = NULL,
  @fecha_incorporacion DATE,
  @fecha_desincorporacion DATE,
  @proveedor VARCHAR(8),
  @situacion INT
AS
  IF @saldo_a_depreciar IS NULL SET @saldo_a_depreciar = @costo_adquisicion / @vida_util
  INSERT INTO ... (and the rest of your procedure)
```

This will calculate @saldo_a_depreciar in two cases: (1) if you don't pass the parameter and (2) if you pass the parameter as null.

Answer (score 1):

You can definitely initialize individual parameters to be `NULL` by default - but I don't think you can do this in your parameter list.

I would do the following:

- if a value is passed in for `@saldo_a_depreciar` - then just use that value as is
- if `NULL` is passed in for `@saldo_a_depreciar` - then do your calculation as the first command in your stored procedure

So I'd write code something like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [SISACT].[new_activo_fijo]
  @activo VARCHAR(8) ,
  @descripcion VARCHAR(60) ,
  @utiliza_serial BIT,
  @serial VARCHAR(20) = NULL,
  @fecha_adquisicion DATE,
  @referencia VARCHAR(10),
  @costo_adquisicion FLOAT,
  @vida_util INT,
  @saldo_a_depreciar FLOAT = NULL,
  @ultimo_periodo CHAR(6),
  @periodo_saldo_cero CHAR(6) = NULL,
  @fecha_incorporacion DATE,
  @fecha_desincorporacion DATE,
  @proveedor VARCHAR(8),
  @situacion INT
AS
   IF @saldo_a_depreciar IS NULL
      SET @saldo_a_depreciar = @costo_adquisicion / @vida_util

   INSERT INTO [SISACT].[ACTIVOS_FIJOS] (
      activo, descripcion, utiliza_serial, serial, fecha_adquisicion, 
      referencia, costo_adquisicion, vida_util, saldo_a_depreciar,
      ultimo_periodo, periodo_saldo_cero, fecha_incorporacion,
      fecha_desincorporacion, proveedor, situacion)
  VALUES(
       @activo, @descripcion, @utiliza_serial, @serial, @fecha_adquisicion,
       @referencia, @costo_adquisicion, @vida_util, @saldo_a_depreciar, 
       @ultimo_periodo, @periodo_saldo_cero,  @fecha_incorporacion,
       @fecha_desincorporacion, @proveedor, @situacion)
```

Answer (score 1):

MS SQL Server does support default values for stored procedures, however you will need to move the calculation for @saldo_a_depreciar into the procedure code after "AS".

```
DECLARE @saldo_a_depreciar FLOAT;
SET @saldo_a_depreciar = @costo_adquisicion / @vida_util;
```